# Import of any files in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I install some utilite with command `npm install utilite` in my angular 2 application. And when i import this utilite in my `app.module.ts`, like this:

```
import { Utilite } from "utilite/utilite";
```

i've got error of not found module. Tell me please, how to write a right import of any modules from node_modules.

Comment: what is `utilite` ?

Comment: Do you use webpack? SystemJS?

Comment: @Michael it is example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import utilite from 'utilite';
```

The syntax

```
import { Utilite } from "utilite/utilite";
```

Will only work if that module explicitly export "Utilite"

Examples of this with moment library:

import moment from 'moment';